# Removing packages previously installed by Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

So I uninstalled *Homebrew*, and didn't remove the packages previously installed by `brew`. Is there any way to remove these packages? Without `brew list` returning anything I don't know where to begin with removing them. I stored a list of the packages so I know which ones to look for but don't know where to find them.

Here's the list:

> - autoconf
> - freetype
> - jasper
> - libtasn1
> - mpfr
> - sane-backends
> - automake
> - gcc
> - jpeg
> - libtiff
> - nettle
> - sqlite
> - boost
> - gd
> - kakoune
> - libtool
> - node
> - tmux
> - carthage
> - gdbm
> - libevent
> - libusb
> - openblas
> - tree
> - chromedriver
> - git
> - libgpg-error
> - libusb-compat
> - openssl
> - unixodbc
> - cscope
> - gmp
> - libgphoto2
> - libyaml
> - pkg-config
> - wget
> - elasticsearch
> - gnutls
> - libicns
> - little-cms2
> - pypy3
> - wine
> - elixir
> - httpie
> - libksba
> - makedepend
> - python
> - wxmac
> - erlang
> - hub
> - libmpc
> - micro
> - python3
> - xz
> - fontconfig
> - isl
> - libpng
> - mongodb
> - readline
> - zeromq
> - mercurial

Comment: What steps or script did you use to uninstall? The tool has been around for a while, so there are different versions of the uninstaller. The good news is /usr/loca/ contains all the files in almost all cases.

Comment: For the uninstaller I ran: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

Answer (score 2):

All packages installed by homebrew should be located in `/usr/local/Cellar/`
I think you can simply remove them from there.

Comment: Don't forget the symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` and possibly stuff in `/usr/local/etc` and possibly others. There is also a cache somewhere in `/Library/Cache` I think.

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/` doesn't exist for me :(

Comment: @Souljacker try ``` which jasper``` for example and that will tell you the path where the bin is installed.

Comment: Thanks @sebastienvg. I found my install path here: `/opt/homebrew/bin/` Looks very sandboxed. The `Cellar` path is now at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar`